# find total number of divisors of number, for t test cases in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, python-itertools

i make a programe to find the number of divisor for a number with test case to submit it on the online judge so i write the code like that

```
num_case=int(raw_input())
num=list()
final_o=[]
for x in xrange(num_case):
     num.append(int(raw_input()))
for h in num:
     result=[int(h)]
for i in xrange(1, h + 1):
    if h % i == 0:
        result.append(i)
a=final_o.append(len(result)-1)
for ff in final_o:
     print ff
```

in this case i make user input the number of test case for example 3 and then enter the number for example 12 7 and 36 then he get the output like this 6 2 9 that the 12 have 6 divisor number and so on this code work well but i get Memory Error when i submit it  so i try to use itertools because range in for loop is small and xrange take a lot of time more than 2 second but i dont get any output code

```
from itertools import count
num_case=int(raw_input())
num=list()
final_o=[]
for x in xrange(num_case):
     num.append(int(raw_input()))
for h in num:
    result=[int(h)]
    n=int(raw_input())
for i in count(1):
    if n % i == 0:
        result.append(i)
    elif count==n+1:
        break
a=final_o.append(len(result)-1)
for ff in final_o:
   print ff
```

any one have a solution to this bug ? Note that the time for the test case 2 second and the range of the numbers is 10^9 and test case 100 How i Do that ?

Comment: I don't understand your algorythm: you put all numbers from 1 to ... in a list and then you run through that list and verify if the elements of that list obey a condition.
Why don't you simply loop through all numbers from 1 to ... and verify if they obey the mentioned condition, without putting all those numbers in a list? (Actually, the list becomes so huge that it doesn't fit in memory anymore)

Comment: i want to get the numbers of divisors of a number the user give me a number and i see the numbers that is divisible by this number from 1 to the number the user give to me i want to make it by a testcase and  after it end i get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def devisors_number(n):
    result = 0
    sqrt_n = int(n**0.5)

    for i in xrange(1, sqrt_n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            result += 1

    result *= 2

    if sqrt_n**2 == n:
        result -= 1

    return result


n = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
d = devisors_number(n)
print "{0} has {1} devisors".format(n, d)
```

Comment: good but i want to put a test case to it and get the result of all number after the case end

Comment: Just add `i` to another range. (and in case `sqrt_n**2==n`, then add this one too :-) )

Comment: many thaaaaaanks to you i edite it  and add  the test case it works and accepted you help me to solve the Memory error thank you again